# Can't link Qt libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: qt, visual-c++, linker, qt-vs-addin

I wanted to switch to VS but struggle to setup Qt.

-I'm using VS Community 2019 16.6.0.
-I installed the Qt plugin
-I get no errors in my code (aka VS can include the libraries)

My linker settings are as follows:

-Ignore import library: `No`
-Additional library directories: `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.8\5.12.8\msvc2017_64\include;$(Qt_LIBPATH_);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`
-Link library dependencies: `Yes`
-Use library dependency inputs: `Yes`

I get lots of linker errors like

> main_window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl QWidget::enterEvent(class QEvent *)" (?enterEvent@QWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQEvent@@@Z)

Comment: I don't think `Additional library directories` is enough but I don't use the addon. I use CMake to generate my Visual Studio projects for Qt

Comment: @drescherjm cmake worked.

Comment: I have used that at work since 2008 when I transitioned from MFC development to Qt.